# What's the best strategy to create initial data in production?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, production

I am creating a spring boot based user management service. I would need the service to be up with a few production ready users when the server is up. What is the best way to have the initial data such as user information etc ready when the service is launched?
I have referred https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.data-initialization
Use of data.sql, *ddl auto* etc are mentioned here, but read in multiple articles that use of such configs are not recommened.
Also, planning to use the property: `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/users?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true` to automatically create the database. *Is it recommended to use this in production?*

Help is needed with a few sample configurations that are used in production to **automatically** create the database, tables, and some initial data to launch the application.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend to use database migration tools like [Liquibase](https://www.liquibase.org/) or [Flyway](https://flywaydb.org/)

They are also very well integrated with Spring Boot:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto.data-initialization.migration-tool